# Why the variable in statictext tool in mfc is undefined

Tags: c++, mfc, undeclared-identifier

I create a static text in a mfc dialog, then I change variable of this static text into CString type and member name is a m_process.
Then, I will use this static text to show the time process, but the identifier not defined.

```
int64 tm1 = cv::getTickCount();
int64 tm2 = cv::getTickCount();
double sec = (tm2-tm1)/cv::getTickFrequency();
teks.Format(_T("%g"),sec);
m_process.SetWindowTextW(teks);
```

and this is the error

> Error 9   error C2065: 'm_process' : undeclared identifier    d:\kuliah\smt 8\bismillah ta\bismillah_dialog\bismillah_dialog\bismillah_dialogdlg.cpp  391 1   Bismillah_Dialog
>
> Error 4   error C2228: left of '.SetWindowTextW' must have class/struct/union d:\kuliah\smt 8\bismillah ta\bismillah_dialog\bismillah_dialog\bismillah_dialogdlg.cpp  268 1   Bismillah_Dialog

this is the declaration of this static text.
in Dlg.cpp

```
CBismillah_DialogDlg::CBismillah_DialogDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(CBismillah_DialogDlg::IDD, pParent)
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
    modeTampil = 0;
    openProcess = 0;
    modeAuto = 0;
    m_area = _T("");
    m_process = _T("");
}

void CBismillah_DialogDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    //  DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDIT1, m_area);
    //  DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDIT2, m_process);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_BUTTON2, m_play);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_BUTTON1, m_open);
    //  DDX_Control(pDX, ID_STATIC, m_pic);
    DDX_Control(pDX, ID_STATIC, m_pic);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_MFCEDITBROWSE1, m_name);
    //  DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDIT3, m_coba);
    //  DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDIT1, m_area);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT1, m_area);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT2, m_process);
}
```

and in the header file.

```
public:
CWinThread* thread;

afx_msg void OnEnChangeMfceditbrowse1();
int modeTampil;
int openProcess;
int modeAuto;
static DWORD ThreadPro(LPVOID *x);
afx_msg void threadProcess();


//  CStatic m_area;
//  CStatic m_process;
    CButton m_play;
    CButton m_open;
//  CStatic m_pic;
    CStatic m_pic;
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedButton1();
    CMFCEditBrowseCtrl m_name;
//  CEdit m_coba;
//  CStatic m_area;
    CString m_area;
    CString m_process;
};
```

The system already declared the static text, but it is not detect when I build this program.
I dont know how to solved it. I'm very confused, and newbie to this MFC. I'm very very need help. thank you :))

Comment: Please show us the code lines, that reports the error...

Comment: You are trying to use `m_process` from outside of the dialog class. You can only access it from a member function of the `CBismillah_DialogDlg` class.

Comment: @acraig5075 I think you have made an assumption there. Either way, the original poster has not made any replies with clarification.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Yes, agreed I have. But it's fitting with the errors of "**undeclared identifier**" and "**left of must have class/struct/union**". If, as you've answered, OP tried to call `SetWindowTextW` on a CString variable, I'd rather expect  "_SetWindowTextW is not a member of CString_".

Comment: @acraig5075 Fair point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your code provided, the UI control is mapped to a `CString` and **not** to a `CEdit`.

Therefore, you **can't** use [SetWindowTextW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633546(v=vs.85).aspx) as `CString` is **not** a control object.

In your can just use:

```
m_process.Format(_T("%g"),sec);
UpdateData(FALSE);
```

I am not saying this is the most efficient way. But it works with your stated code. There are other ways to transfer control content to variables (for example: [SetDlgItemText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645521(v=vs.85).aspx)) but this is how I do it. No doubt there are even more methods.

Comment: I don't agree with that. Depending on what you do, it is much simpler and faster to directly set the data. Suppose you have 50 controls. Why should I transfer data from 50 controls to the UI, also in this case you have to transfer the data from the UI to the internal storage first, otherwise you override data the user just enters.

Comment: You don't have to do it the way I have stated. I clearly state it is **one way**, and my way. I directly include a **secondary** way too. Either way, my answer was to **his** question. He is using a `CString` and he **can't** use `SetWindowTextW` with it. I feel your down vote unfair. If my answer was dogmatic, then I would have taken it on the chin. But it is not dogmatic.